# EXT4-fs (v mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

Tags: kernel, restore

I need some help.

My Ubuntu can't load droplet. Server is on Digital Ocean, and now I can run server on recover mode, but I don't know what I have to do for normal loading mode.
I don't have any restore point

I take error:

`new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored EXT4-fs (vda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)`

This is my kern.log and syslog.log
https://easyupload.io/m/2960cb

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Similar but mine showed up like this with an attached SSD: `EXT4-fs (sdg1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)`